# How to properly use django-cms apphooks

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-cms

Below is my django cms apphook, its showing the app on the drop down but it doesn't hook the application to a page.

The project is in django 2.1.11, python3.7.1, and django cms 3.6.0

I have tried to change the apphook file to `cms_apps.py` and `cms_app.py`. I have also tried [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dj8dhgmzlFM&t=2903s).

I would be happy if someone can share a working manual for this procedure.

```py
from cms.app_base import CMSApp
from cms.apphook_pool import apphook_pool

@apphook_pool.register # register the application
class PeoplemanagerApphook(CMSApp):
    app_name = "peoplemanager"
    name = "People Application"
    def get_urls(self, page=None, language=None, **kwargs):
        return ["peoplemanager.urls"]
```

The page loads, however it does not display the contents of the model

Comment: Is the indentation shown here the same as in your code? `class` should be at the same level as `@apphook_pool.register`.

Comment: HI dirkgroten, no. that was just a typing error when posting the code. the class is in the same level as the @apphook_pool.register

Comment: Can you post `peoplemanager.urls`? I'm curious what the URLs are given than you say it's not loading the app. Also try to restart the server, just to check it's had a chance to load your URLs.